# java: NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces() fails on Windows

Tags: java, networking

I'm trying to enumerate all MAC addresses using java on a Windows machine. I'm using a code that works well on MacOs and Linux, but if I run on Windows 7, it hangs for about a minute and then returns without a useful result.
It hangs in the very begining of my code:

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> ni = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
```

I have debugged in Netbeans and it hangs in ClassLoader.java in function findNative(). The code it hangs in is the second line of the below:

```
synchronized (libs) {
    int size = libs.size();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `libs`? Can you post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)?

Comment: Works on my Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Seems that the lack of results is caused by securitymanager permissions. Still no idea about the one minute hang.